# Does flamingo supports right-to-left ribbon menu?

Tags: java, swing, ribbon, right-to-left, radiance-flamingo

I want to provide a java application with a Microsoft Ribbon like view. After a quick search I found the flamingo project useful. The problem is that I want to have a right-to-left ribbon menu and I can not. I just want to know if the API provides any support for right-to-left ribbon tasks, ribbonbands, etc?

I did try to set component orientation for an instance of JRibbonBand in this way:

```
JRibbonBand band1 = new JRibbonBand band1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

and also for the main ribbon :

```
frame.getRibbon().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Unfortunately it did not work except for the application menu button (the circular button on the top).

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: please what's wrong with [this](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/04/03/right-to-left-support-for-the-ribbon-in-flamingo-5-0.html) or [this](http://www.java.net/story/kirill-grouchnikov-right-left-support-ribbon-flamingo-50), are you sure that doesn't works with Substance Office Blue ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

I found that I should invoke **applyComponentOrientation** instead of setComponentOrientation for a ribbon instance to switch to RTL mode.